# Let user pick which content will be visible on search

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, views

User can make event that can be visible on their profile.

There is also main view page with filters that has all events made by all users.

I want to give users option (YES/NO) to have the event listed on main view page with filters.

First what i think of is make simple vocabulary with terms YES and NO and in view filter show only those that have YES.

Since each term has its own link i don't want links YES and NO with all the content they have to be visible by search engines or somehow to be found by users.
I know i can disable them in robots.txt but maybe there is more simple solution to this ?